# In R vector, how to convert each number to a string?

Tags: r, vector

I wanted to generate a vector of string as the following:

```
c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8",......)
```

The length of this vector is a variable (number of rows counted from a csv file).

Do I have to generate an integer vector firstly, using something like seq (from, to), and then loop through it to convert each number to a string?

Comment: You would not need to use a loop - `as.character(some_numeric_vector)`. Or even better, `row.names(df)` should already be a `character` vector, if `df` is the `data.frame` you read your file into.

Comment: Try `as.character(1:nrow(YourDataFrame))`

Comment: I guess `paste` would save a few keystrokes compared to `as.character`: `paste(1:nrow(dat))`.

Comment: Or `paste(seq_len(nrow(foo)))`